# Dynamic alternate right left alignement

Tags: html, css

Let's say I'm pulling text from multiple posts in a  MySQL database chronologically using PHP. I want my posts to be displayed as alternatively aligned to right and left.

Importantly, I want the posts to be able to be deleted. If a post is deleted, I want the other posts to retain the dynamic alternating alignment.

Can you give me some ideas on how to do this using CSS?

Comment: Do you mean you want the posts to be deleted dynamically, and then all the other rows to be re-colored?

Comment: No, I don't plan to have dynamic things whizzing around. This is really good enough for my first fully fledged app-from-scratch. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `:odd` and `:even` pseudoClasses

e.g.

```
div:nth-child(odd) { text-align: left }
div:nth-child(even) { text-align: right }
```

if you want to retain the previous order after a post deletion, just set `display: none` when you remove the post (instead of removing the node from the DOM)

If you want instead reposition dinamycally all following posts just remove entirely  the node

Comment: How is browser support for those pseudo classes? (not snarky, just a real question)

Comment: Interesting. Does this mean that every 2 child element of a div will be aligned right. Or do I have to give a certain ID to each div element?

Comment: @Joseph, see some demo/article on subject, like http://davidwalsh.name/css-tables-css3-alternate-row-colors - no id required

Comment: This won't work in IE < 9, but you could use javascript to set the styles dynamically in those cases.

Answer (score 2):

After you've received your results from the db, put a classname into a php variable. In the foreach loop, switch back and forth between two classnames as the loop is running. Like so:

```
//php file 
$alt = 'Row';

foreach($results as $row) {
    echo '<div class="' . $alt . '">some content</div>';
    $alt = ($alt == 'Row') ? 'altRow' : 'Row';
}
```

and then in your stylesheet:

```
.Row {
    text-align: left;
}

.altRow { 
    text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: I'd use `foreach($results as $key => $row){$odd = $key&1 ? 'odd' : 'even';}`

Comment: performing a binary & is much quicker than a string comparison - and it's 1 less line of code

Comment: @Mikey can you point me to some docs on your method? I've never seen that before. Thanks!